# Как программно добавить LinearLayout?

Tags: android

Есть (LinearLayout) 1
Есть (LinearLayout) 2 из 3 TextView.

Как программно взять XML LinearLayout 2, сделать 3 копии и добавить их в LinearLayout1?

Типо ListView?

Ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: inflate гуглите

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сделал как вы сказали почитал про inflate, но получил ошибку, вон выше выложил.

Comment: `view1` надо также заинфлэйтить как и `view`, а не пытаться добавить в разметку элемент, коий в неё уже загружен, о чём и сообщает вам ваша ошибка.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, все равно не работает
`View view1=new View(MainActivity.this);
                    view1=view;
                    linearLayout.addView(view1);`

Comment: Удалите строку    view1=view;

Comment: Тогда view1 буджет пусйто

Comment: Как я уже писал вам надо заинфлейтить разметку еще раз для вью1

Comment: Ок, все зациклил в for и сработало, спасибо)

Comment: А как закрывать такие темы где нет ответов?

Comment: Лучший вариант-самому написать ответ к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView==null){
                convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.in_list,null);

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();
                View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.asd, null);

                TextView textView0= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                textView0.setText("Текст");

                TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                TextView textView2= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView textView3= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

                textView.setText("первый");
                textView2.setText("второй");
                textView3.setText("третий");


                LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.asd);
                linearLayout.addView(view);
            }

            return convertView;
```

Ответ